# FireDac Call Function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, delphi, firedac

My code :

```
FDStoredProc1.StoredProcName := 'aaaaa' ;
with FDStoredProc1.Params do begin
  Clear;
  with Add do begin
    ParamType := ptInput;
    DataType := ftInteger;
  end;
end;  
FDStoredProc1.Params[0].Value := StrToint(edit1.Text) ;
edit1.Text := FDStoredProc1.ExecFunc() ;
```

My code in Oracle :

```
create or replace FUNCTION AAAAA (pn number) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
  update dmnv set thuong = pn  ; 
  commit  ; 
  RETURN '3' 
END AAAAA;
```

There is no error when running, but the parameter is `NULL` at  Oracle Server (version 12). So function is `exec` on Server with wrong parameter (the true parameter is the value in edit1.text).I have typed a number at edit1.

Comment: Change 'aaaaa' to 'AAAAA' and try again. All identifiers in an Oracle database are UPPER CASE by default. Best of luck.

Comment: Non-quoted identifiers are not case sensitive, and are treated as uppercase. So it shouldn't matter, except if firedac would implicitly add quotes around the stored proc name, which would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

Give the parameter a name.

```
  with Add do begin
    Name := 'pn';
    ParamType := ptInput;
    DataType := ftInteger;
  end;
```

Comment: [FireDac][Phys][Ora]-338.Param [pn] type changed from [ftMTBcd] to [ftInteger].Query must be reprepared.Possible reason an assigment to a TFDparam.AsXXX property implitcitly changed the parameter data type.Hint : use the TFDParam.Value or appropriate TFDParam.asXXX property.

Answer (score 0):

```
with FDQuery1.SQL do begin
    Clear;
    Add('begin');
    Add('  select  aaaaa(8) from dual ;');
    Add('end;');
 end;
 FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Also get error.a INTO clause is expected